# How can I transfer music files from Rythymbox to my mp3 player (gpx)

Tags: 12.04

How can I sync my music on Rhythmbox to transfer to my mp3 player? gpx to be specific..

Comment: Been at it for Three days...Trouble is the Rhymnbox pictured on the Ubuntu user guide looks nothing like the one in my system. Black and White and No options that I can find -Other than downloading music from other sources To it and playing the same..but No provision for transferring music to an Mp3